# Memory allocation R services SQL server 2016

Tags: r, memory, limit, allocation, sql-server-2016

I have a problem of memory allocation with R service (on SQL server 2016)

This my error : 
*"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb"*

That's happened when R exceed 1,2G in memory (I'm looking the Task Manager)

I already changed in the file rlaucher (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.RSERVICES\MSSQL\Binn) the MEMORY LIMIT PERCENT up to 90 but nothing change.

My computer has 8G of RAM, so normally my R session can allocate 7,2G in memory. (90% of 8G)

what/where is the problem ? Is there an other file which limit the memory specialy for the new R service with SQL server 2016 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which algorithms are you using in SQL R Service ?

Comment: I'm creating some models with the Random Forest algorithms. That's why I needed to allocate a lot of memory

Comment: the SQL R Services work good with the algorithms or libraries provided by revolution r. they work for large datasets also but if you other libraries you might not be able to scale them for large datasets. the libraries provided  by revolution r are optimized internally to run within the SQL R Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the memory allocated for R process in the Resource pool's max_memory_percent settings, using instructions on [How To: Create a Resource Pool for R](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703706.aspx). For more information please see [Resource Governance for R services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703708.aspx).